# Angular - Force ng-form $invalid

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-form

Angular has a bunch of rules for form validation but I can't find any documentation for adding additional rules to be validated.

***Example***: A user must enter their email, and confirm their email in a second field.

Is there an Angular way to add rules like: `if (email !== confEmail) { form.$invalid = true, etc.. }` without polluting my controllers?

**Edit**: Found what I was looking for. Looks like it's new to Angular 1.3 :) http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html

Tutorial to walk you through adding new $validator directives

Comment: Add validation rules to input fields, as long as at least one field  is invalid so is the form. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms